# Having a hard time deleting rows based on column values

Tags: r

I was given two vectors: `radonLocation` and `radonAverage`. `radonLocation` describes the location of a home where radon levels were tested (Basement or 1st floor), and `radonAverage` is the average radon level detected.

I combined the two vectors to form a data frame. Now, I want to create a subset that only includes the average radon levels for "Basement"

```
radonLocation <- c("Basement", "1st Floor", "Basement", "1st Floor", "Basement", "1st Floor")
radonAverage <- c(5.37,  1.96, 10.67,  3.49,  5.87,  2.80)

Location <- cbind(radonLocation)
Location <- as.data.frame(Location)
colnames(Location) <- c("Loc")
Location[] <- lapply(Location, as.character)
class(Location$Loc)

Location$Avg <- radonAverage
Basement <- Location[Location$Loc != "1st Floor", ]
```

I have no idea what is wrong with my last line of code, because I can't seem to get a subset which only includes values for basement. I made sure to convert the location variable `("Loc")` into a character from a factor, I double checked my code, but I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: With your example, I can't reproduce the error and I get the expected dataframe with 3 rows all corresponding to `Basement`

Comment: I have no clue what's going on :( but it won't work

Comment: I am working on a Mac, could that be an issue?

Comment: My dataset consists of 118 observations but I didn't think that such a distinction would matter

Comment: I also scraped the data in from a website and compiled each variable into a vector, but I didn't think that would it affect it either

Comment: Sorry I am still learning R, what is `str`

Comment: For the mini: `data.frame: 6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Loc: chr  "Basement" "1st Floor" "Basement" "1st Floor" ...
 $ Avg: num  5.37 1.96 10.67 3.49 5.87 ...` And for the extended: `data.frame: 118 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Loc: chr  " Basement" " 1st Floor" " Basement" " 1st Floor" ...
 $ Avg: num  5.37 1.96 10.67 3.49 5.87 ...` The same exact thing

Comment: Not the same, you have "1st Floor" and " 1st Floor". Try `Basement <- Location[Location$Loc != " 1st Floor", ]` on your extended dataframe

Comment: OMG I just noticed it. There are spaces between the words. I feel so incredibly stupid

Comment: No worries, it happens to everyone ;) please deleted useless comments to clarify your post.